# detecting outer circle using opencv HoughCircles

Tags: opencv

I am trying to detect two concentric circles using [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv) in Android. Big outer circle is red, inner smaller circle is blue. The idea is to detect big circle while distance is long and detect inner circle as the distance becomes short.

[Sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q0iD.png)

I am using simple code:

```
Mat matRed = new Mat();
Core.inRange(matHsv, getScalar(hue - HUE_D, saturation - SAT_D, brightness - BRIGHT_D), getScalar(hue + HUE_D, saturation + SAT_D, brightness + BRIGHT_D), matRed);
//here we have black-white image
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(matRed, matRed, new Size(0, 0), 6, 6);
Mat matCircles = new Mat();
Imgproc.HoughCircles(matRed, matCircles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, matRed.rows()/8, 100, param2, 0, 0);
```

After calling `inRange` we have white ring on black background. `HoughCircles` function detects only inner black circle.
How can I make it to detect outer white circle instead?

Comment: do you have a sample image?

Comment: Use Canny on the image and then HoughCircles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing a sample image (or being quite sure what you mean by 'detect big circle while distance is long and detect inner circle as the distance becomes short'), this is somewhat of a guess, but I'd suggest using [Canny edge detect](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html) to get the boundaries of your circles and then using [contours](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) to extract the edges. You can use the [contour hierarchy](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html) to determine which is inside which if you need to extract one or the other.

Additionally, given the circles are different colours, you might want to look at using inRange to segment based on colour; for example, [this post from PyImageSearch](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/) contains a Python application which does colour-based tracking.

Comment: As I know canny edge detector uses greyed image. When color image have converted to greyed we lost information. The additional color information can be useful in complicated conditions (raining, snowing and etc.)

Comment: The tutorials I linked to contain code samples; I think you'd be better off adapting those to your purposes, especially given I don't know exactly what you're trying to do. It's true, converting to grey will lose information, but you can keep a copy of the colour image and use it to do some additional processing. You might want to look at using inRange to segment based on colour; see [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/) for an example Python application which does colour-based tracking.

Comment: @BeloweeP. I've seen your suggested edit with your code; I'd suggest posting it as your own answer rather than appending it to mine. For one, it means you get the credit; for another, I don't think it's quite what I suggested doing. (If it works for you, cool! But I feel adding it to my answer would be misleading.)